# Permutations of multiple data items in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some data in a base table equivalent to:

```
EmployeeID,Department,Role,Location
-----------------------------------
001,HR,Support,Bristol
002,Banking,Partner,Sheffield
etc.
```

I then have an additional three tables that contain any additional department, role or location when it is applicable to an individual, but these are simply populated with the EmployeeID and additional piece of information, e.g.

```
EmployeeID,Location
-------------------
001,London
```

Where it is populated, I need to take every permutation, for example if the person had an additional location of London, as above, I'd expect to generate two rows:

```
001,HR,Support,Bristol
001,HR,Support,London
```

If the person had an additional role as a secretary, I'd expect four rows, however:

```
001,HR,Support,Bristol
001,HR,Support,London
001,HR,Secretary,Bristol
001,HR,Secretary,London
```

For clarity, I'd expect to see any record in the base table that does not match in the multiple table too.  So fundamentally in the above example I'd expect five rows:

```
001,HR,Support,Bristol
001,HR,Support,London
001,HR,Secretary,Bristol
001,HR,Secretary,London
002,Banking,Partner,Sheffield
```

Hopefully that makes some sense

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
with departmentX as
(
select EmployeeID, Department from Employee
union
select EmployeeId, Department from Department
),
roleX as
(
select EmployeeID, Role from Employee
union
select EmployeeId, Role from Role
),
locationX as
(
select EmployeeID, Location from Employee
union
select EmployeeId, Location from Location
)
select d.EmployeeId, d.department, r.Role, l.Location
from
departmentX d join roleX r 
on d.EmployeeId = r.EMployeeId
join locationX l on d.employeeId = l.EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got an solution - you can do it by using small steps:

1) Find every Departments for the employees

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Department FROM dbo.additionalDepartments
UNION
SELECT EmployeeID, Department FROM dbo.baseTable
```

2) Find every Roles for the employees

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Role FROM dbo.additionalRoles
UNION
SELECT EmployeeID, Role FROM dbo.baseTable
```

3) Find every Locations for the employees

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Location FROM dbo.additionalLocations
UNION
SELECT EmployeeID, Location FROM dbo.baseTable
```

4) Join them all :)

```
SELECT D.EmployeeID, D.Department, R.Role, L.Location FROM
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, Department FROM dbo.additionalDepartments
    UNION
    SELECT EmployeeID, Department FROM dbo.baseTable
) D
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, Role FROM dbo.additionalRoles
    UNION
    SELECT EmployeeID, Role FROM dbo.baseTable
) R ON D.EmployeeID = R.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, Location FROM dbo.additionalLocations
    UNION
    SELECT EmployeeID, Location FROM dbo.baseTable
) L ON D.EmployeeID = L.EmployeeID
```

Please check my SQL Fiddle. I've built your scenario at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/756fd/2/0